# Port forwarding with iptables -> connection refused

Tags: iptables, nat

I am trying to redirect requests to my local IP (10.42.42.152) on port 80 to a remote server, e.g. google.com (173.194.113.104:80). The remote server is up, ip_forward is enabled but I only get "connection refused".

```
root@raspi:~# telnet 10.42.42.152 80
Trying 10.42.42.152...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Show that ip forwarding is enabled:

```
root@raspi:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

The following are my default iptables rules:

```
# /etc/iptables.up.rules
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Sep 26 10:22:12 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [8542:1505054]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [476:105829]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6274:968245]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 26 10:22:12 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Sep 26 10:22:12 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [533:70053]
:INPUT ACCEPT [491:65475]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [685:60069]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [683:59949]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.42.42.4
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 26 10:22:12 2014
```

Load these rules (only for my VPN to work), then add two other rules:

```
root@raspi:~# iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
root@raspi:~# /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.42.42.152 -j DNAT --to-destination 173.194.113.104:80
root@raspi:~# /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

Show that the IP address 10.42.42.152 belongs to the local device:

```
root@raspi:~# ip address show eth0 | grep 152
    inet 10.42.42.152/24 brd 10.42.42.255 scope global secondary eth0:152

root@raspi:~# ping 10.42.42.152 -c 1
PING 10.42.42.152 (10.42.42.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.42.152: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.347 ms
--- 10.42.42.152 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.347/0.347/0.347/0.000 ms
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration works as is but not for local requests. So if some other host in the network (e.g. from 10.42.42.15) tries to connect, everything should work as expected.

For connections from localhost I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113651

Just add:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.42.42.152 -j DNAT --to-destination 173.194.113.104:80
```

Comment: This works. Thaaaaaank you!

Comment: Love you, it costs me 3 hours to figure out this :D